# Can't seem to use Func in Unity c3?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

If I try this

```
private System.Action blah;
```

it works fine. For some reason

```
private System.Func blah;
```

> Assets/scripts/objects/flite groups/MassiveExplisions.cs(130,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Func' does not exist in the namespace`System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I don't get it, why can I not use `Func`?  This is in ordinary up-to-date Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) type because it is the way to encapsulate a method that does not return a value.

There is no type called `Func` because it always returns some value and you need to specify the type of its value. For example [`Func<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I am not allowed to accept an answer for 11 minutes.  Thanks again!  No more answers needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `Func` need at least one generic type as return type for the delegate.

```
private System.Func<bool> simple;
private System.Func<bool, int, double> withParams;
```

Usage :

```
bool result = simple();
bool result = withParams(10, 0.2);
```

If you don't need return type, use `Action`.